# Можно ли над методом REST-контроллера ставить аннотацию @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, rest, транзакции, jta

Можно ли над методом REST-контроллера ставить аннотацию `@Transactional`?

Будут ли проблемы, если одновременно по этому URL одновременно будут пытаться получить данные несколько клиентов?

Comment: Эта аннотация используется там где транзакции - какие-то операции которые требуют полного завершения. Пример таких операций работа с бд. Следовательно Эта аннотация должна быть только там де идет обращение к бд. Поставить ее в контроллере можно, но при этом какое будет поведение очень сложно сказать. Не рекомендуется в общем.

Comment: C какого хотя бы пакета ваша @Transactional? Со спрингового?

Comment: @RomanDanilov Да

Comment: @Tsyklop Неверное предположение. Поняти *можно* или *нельзя* можно толковать по разному. Я могу сказать что можно *все*. Хотя это ни очем не говорит. Возможности языка Java практически не ограничены, комментарий бесполезен.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

См. внизу о том, какой слой использовать.

---

Здесь я укажу некоторые ссылки:

- [Слой использования `@Transactional` анотации.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23316154/573032).

> Что лучше всего с `@Transactional`, вы должны положить его, если у вас
> есть доступ к базе данных.
>
> См. «Понимание реализации декларативной транзакции Spring Framework»
>
> ```
>  вы просто аннотируете свои классы аннотацией @Transactional, добавляете в свою конфигурацию строку (`<tx: annotation-driven />`), а
> ```
>
> затем ожидаете, что вы поймете, как все это работает.

- [Какой слой использовать для транзакций и сессии Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31841446/573032).

> Лучше всего использовать управление транзакциями Spring. Аннотации
> `@Transactional` для использования транзакций. На заводе-изготовителе
> используется `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. Все бины управляются Spring-ом,
> поэтому у вас нет забот.
>
> **Транзакции принадлежат сервисному уровню**.  Например, если у вас есть `SomeService`, то код будет выглядеть так:
>
> ```
> @Service ("someService") @Transactional public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {@Autowired SomeDao someDao;  // Остальной код опущен ...}
> ```

- [Spring Hibernate - различие между CrudRepository и SessionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234350/573032).

> Просто вы можете найти описание этих аннотаций на сайте docs Spring.
>
> В ближайшее время, чтобы ответить на ваши вопросы, разница между ними
> заключается в том, что они используются для разных целей.
>
> ```
>  @Transactional используется для демаркации кода, участвующего в транзакции. Он помещается на классы и методы.
>
>  @Repository используется для определения Spring-компонента, поддерживающего транзакции, его также можно использовать в DI.
> ```
>
> Они могут использоваться как в одном классе.

Comment: О каких проблемах вы говорите?

Comment: @RomanDanilov Я говорю о проблемах с `@Transactional`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите более конкретное описание возможных проблем и дайте ссылку на место в документации, где об этом написано.

Comment: @Hivemaster Обновил со ссылками на мои предыдущие ответы.

Answer (score 9):

Можно. Никаких технических ограничений для этого нет. Но не нужно, так как это неправильно с точки зрения проектирования архитектуры. Ни контроллеры, ни слой доступа к данным не могут располагать необходимыми знаниями о взаимосвязях данных, в контексте которых имеет смысл транзакции применять. Это прерогатива сервисного слоя, в котором и должна располагаться вся бизнес-логика.

**UPDATE:** Так как правильность моего ответа ставят под сомнение, придётся его дополнить.

Во-первых, мне приходилось видеть проекты крупных и солидных компаний, в которых на протяжении многих лет транзакции успешно используется именно в web-слое. Во-вторых, первая же ссылка в Google по запросу "spring @transactional @controller" ведёт на большой SO, где [люди делятся тем же опытом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44332307/1911548). Наконец, не может быть более железного аргумента, чем рабочий код. Поэтому я накидал простенький проект и залил его на GitHub - https://github.com/TheDeadOne/spring-transactional-controller-demo.

Comment: Это неверный ответ, потому что *нелзя*, поэтому спринг предлагает правильную архитектуру. А в неправильной он просто работать *правильно* не может.

Comment: @RomanC в моём ответе, по-моему, ясно описана разница между технической возможностью и архитектурной нежелательность. Оперировать категориями вида "нельзя потому что нельзя" уместно в вопросах потребления манной каши. И если уж быть точным, многослойная архитектура была придумана и разграничила области ответственности задолго до появления Spring.

Comment: Вопрос был такой "Можно ли над методом рест-контроллера ставить аннотацию @Transactional?".

Answer (score 2):

**Можно**

Пост процессор, увидев аннотацию @Transactional вокруг аннотированного класса создаст прокси, в котором будут происходить (очень примерно) две вещи

1. Выполняться beginTransaction()  перед аннотированным методом (или
   перед каждым публичным методом аннотированного класса)
2. Выполняться .getTransaction().commit()  после аннотированного метода
   (или после каждого публичного метода аннотированного класса)

С точки зрения многопоточности от заворачивания контроллера в прокси ничего не меняется.

**Но не нужно**

А вот с точки зрения архитектуры это плохая идея. Первая буква в слове SOLID:
The Single Responsibility Principle
Ответственность контроллера - получить request и попросить кого нибудь его обработать и отправить ответ. Не надо вешать на него дополнительную функциональность.